# Do Guild Wars 2 Beta characters carry over to the full release?

Tags: guild-wars-2

If you play the beta will you be able to access your characters in the full game when released?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but at the original Guild Wars launch, character names were reserved for your account and their appearance customizations were preserved, but all mission and quest progress was wiped; you started at level 1 with starter items.

Comment: Leaving this closed, as the answer was "No" and is now no longer applicable since the beta is long past.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, it will not carry over.

From the [official FAQ](http://www.guildwars2.com/en/the-game/game-faq/#thirty-six)

> Will the progress I make during a Guild Wars 2 Beta Event carry over
>   when Guild Wars 2 launches?
>
> No. Everything will be wiped in preparation for launch.

Comment: But those who prepurchased *will* get a headstart, I believe.

Comment: Yes, 3 days, to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, Beta characters don't carry over.

One of the reasons for wiping their characters database is to to give players the equal chance of Leveling, gearing and learning the game from scratch.

Not wiping their characters database would lead to overall unfair advantages given to the beta-tester players.

Also, the coolest names would be unavailable already

Comment: Also, what if someone finds a bug in beta that lets them level up crazy fast or earn way too much gold?

Comment: @Shadur Then that person is crowned King of All Videogames and we all pledge fealty to them.